Why aren't photo editors accepting URIs from the photo picker?
I want to request a photo from the user using the system photo picker (i.e. with a PickVisualMedia request), then send another Intent for a photo editor to crop the photo. If I just send the URI received from the photo picker with the intent, Google Photos shows "Error, could not load media" and quits. Other photo editors I have either show a similar warning or just crash.
The code that registers the launchers for the media picker and crop activity:
mediaPickerLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()
) { uri ->
    pickerCallback(uri)
}

cropResultLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        Log.d("Crop", "Photo received")
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Crop", "Cancelled!")
    }
}

pickerCallback checks if the URI is null, and if it isn't, runs this:
val intent = Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")
intent.setData(uri)
intent.putExtra("crop", "true")
// Set the aspect ratio to 1:1 (square)
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1)
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1)
// Set the resolution to 500x500
intent.putExtra("outputX", 500)
intent.putExtra("outputY", 500)
// Set a few more flags
intent.putExtra("return-data", true)
cropResultLauncher!!.launch(intent)

I tried using takePersistableUriPermission, as described in the media picker article, but it didn't help.

In the end, Rashid Bilal's answer worked, but I had to add this line to pickerCallback after the line that creates the intent:
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)


The issue you are facing is most probably because the URI provided by the media picker doesn't grant sufficient permissions for other apps to access the content. To resolve this, you can create a FileProvider and use it to generate a content URI that can be accessed by other apps.
Use this file provider in Manifest.xml "use you app package in the authorities tag"
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${appPackage}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

Then create file_path.xml in the res/xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>

Then use this function in pickerCallback to create a temp file from the Uri
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val tempFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "temp_image.jpg")
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
inputStream?.copyTo(outputStream)
inputStream?.close()
outputStream.close()

Then get the file uri like this
val tempUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"${packageName.provider}",tempFile)
Then you can use thiss tempUri in the Crop Intent

Thanks for your response, but photo editors still don't work, but now Google Photos says "Editing is not supported for this image". The image is a regular JPEG. I suspect that this is because the file is located in the Android/data folder, as another photo editor shows "Access denied" instead.

Samsung Gallery showed a SecurityException in logcat that mentions opening a provider that isn't exported, but making the provider exported makes the app crash when started. (Here's the exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{ad7784f 28182:com.sec.android.gallery3d:crop/u0a113} (pid=28182, uid=10113) that is not exported from UID 10366)

It looks like I fixed it - I just had to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION).
